# ESEUTIL.EXE version 8.3.106.1

Tags: exchange-2007, scdpm

I need to get a 32-bit version of the eseutil.exe (version 8.3.106.1) for the purposes of Microsoft DPM 2007 backing up an Exchange 2007 SP3 server.  I can't grab the one off of the Exchange server since it's 64-bit.  I downloaded the SP3 Exchange Management Tools (x86), but the version included is slightly older at 8.3.83.0.  Does anyone know where I can find this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  I downloaded the x86 version of KB2279665 which was an .msp file.  I then used the utility found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2006/04/07/571138.aspx) to extract the .cab's from the .msp.  At that point, I used 7-Zip to extract the eseutil.exe file that I needed for DPM.  It's x86 and it's version 8.3.106.1.  Phew!

Answer (score 1):

One ridiculously convoluted option would be to install 32-bit Exchange on a system (the evaluation versions have a 32-bit installer available, even though it's unsupported), and patch it up to current; hopefully that should give you the correct eseutil.exe.

Comment: :( I hope there's a better option out there.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb808827.aspx#ExchangeServerDatabaseUtilities), ESEUtil should be a part of the [Exchange 2007 Management Tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=112325).

Be sure to update them to SP1/2/3 if your Exchange is SP1/2/3 as well.

Comment: I actually am running Exchange 2007 SP3 and downloaded the Exchange 2007 Management Tools SP3 (as mentioned above), but the versions are slightly off since I've since applied some updates to the server that brought the eseutil.exe version to 8.3.106.1, while the one that is provided in the SP3 downloaded you linked to contains 8.3.83.0.  In this case, it's close, but no cigar.  DPM fails.

Comment: Run a windows update on the machine that has Management Tools installed. According to MS: "You use the Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 management tools to maintain up-to-date copies of eseutil.exe and ese.dll. " ... "The management tools are supported by all update methods such as Microsoft Update and Microsoft Systems Management Server (SMS)."  ... If you're not able to keep it fully up to date, then it's seems it's not working as intended.